# How to prevent user from dragging in a file as input during read -n command

Tags: bash, macos, user-input

I have a bash script that asks the user for single-key inputs to select from some menu screens. I'm using `read -n 1 -s -r -p ''` and then doing stuff based on the user input passed through a small set of if statements.

I need to be able to prevent the user from accidentally dragging in a file acting as an input to the read command. I'm very open to replacing the `read` command to then allow me to prevent this user action from disrupting the process, but I need this to be compatible with most shells.

Right now, as one would expect, dragging in a file enters the filepath in the terminal, and so the shell treats it as if the user actually pressed keys.

I do not want the user to be able to use copy/paste or dragging in a file as a way to respond to the read prompt.

Is this possible? I don't mind if it's complex and probably not worth it; I'd implement it anyway I'm sure :D

I'm not familiar with official shell names, but I want it to be at least compatible with Mac OSX Terminal and Ubuntu.

Comment: done! thanks for the info!

Comment: I would be critical to know what OS/desktop/terminal? Is this Windows with WSL? Mac? Linux/Gnome? KDE? LXDE? Fluxbox?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin mac osx terminal and ubuntu

Comment: @DogeCode : I think a similar problem would arise, if the user accidentally presses the Apple-V key combination to paste the current content of the clipboard. Hence, the general problem is that the user enters more than one character: You want to get rid everrything else. Since you likely don't want to give up the convenience of `-n 1`, the solution would be to empty the keyboard buffer immediately after the `read`. I don't know whether there is a buildin way to do this, so perhaps you have to write a loop, reading one character at a time, until nothing is available anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARTIAL ANSWER
*(stops user dragging in a file or directory but not from copy/pasting)*

There is probably a more reliable and functional method but I have no idea.

Inspired by @user1934428 's suggestion about emptying the keyboard buffer, I came across a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/bd1oy9/how_do_i_clear_keyboard_buffer/) including the Perl command that clears the buffer. I did some trial and error, and found that this works perfectly:

```
read -n 1 -s -r -p '' && perl -e 'use POSIX; tcflush(0, TCIFLUSH);'
while [[ "$REPLY" == *"/"* ]] || [ "$REPLY" = "" ]; do
    read -n 1 -s -r -p '' && perl -e 'use POSIX; tcflush(0, TCIFLUSH);'
done
```

After clearing the buffer, conveniently $REPLY is left with a "/" in memory from a file and is left empty from a directory.

This allows me to use that while loop to wait until the user has not dragged in a file or directory and do different things based on which.

**This does not fix the copy/paste issue however.**

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to prevent Copy/Pasting (or the equivalent dragging of files). This service is provided by the window manager, and is not controlled by applications.

That said, consider implementing the flushing using pure bash - flush the buffer BEFORE prompting the user for input, and after taking the data. This can be done by forcing a timeout  on the read.

The solution will also prevent feeding the program with input from a pipe, or similar/file. I'll leave it to OP to decide if this is desired.

```
# Read all pending input
while read -t 0.1 ; do : ; done
# Read input
read -n 1 -s -r -p ''
# Consume any remaining input
while read -t 0.1 ; do : ; done
```